# QuickBlox Multiple Video Chat

Tags: quickblox

We have integrated the single video conferencing with quickblox in iOS and are working perfectly.Now we need to implement multiple video conferencing facility in iOS.For that I tried to create two instances of 
 [[QBChat instance] callUser:user.ID conferenceType:QBVideoChatConferenceTypeAudioAndVideo];

and set different UIImageviews in the

`- (UIImageView *) viewToRenderOpponentVideoStream` datasource method based on the instances.I tried to establish multiple communication between the users using 3 devices.But the server allows only 2 devices to communicate each other.Is there any way to allow the third device to establish communications between the third device and other 2 devices?